# Migration in cakephp5

Tags: php, database, cakephp, migration, database-migration

I install a userManager plugion in my app that i've used before, so it has 6 table already define in the plugin. in the past i've tried Django and the is a migration function so you can biuld the tables from the structures already define in the code, i figured that i could do the same here in cakephp, but i'm running into some issues.

i have all the tables and entities define inside the plugin in Proyect/plugins/NameOfPlugin/src/Model and /Entity

i was reading the Doc on cake site and it said that i should run this command

```
bin/cake bake migration_snapshot Initial --plugin MyPlugin
```

When i run this comand a new file is generated in Proyect/plugins/NameOfPlugin/src/config/migrations as i undestand that is the file that then will be use to build the tables in my database, the thing is that is only biulding 2 of the 6 tables that are define, the docs says that this comand will look through your application `Table` classes and will only add the model tables in the snapshot, i check the definitions of all the tables and all of them are correct.

All the tables are related in this schema, could this be generating a problem?

This are the table definitions

```
class RolesUsersTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('user_roles');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('UserManager.Userstamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'LEFT',
            'className' => 'UserManager.Users',
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Roles', [
            'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
            'className' => 'UserManager.Roles',
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('UsersLog', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_log_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
            'className' => 'UserManager.UsersLog',
        ]);
    }
...
}
```

```
class RolesTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('roles');
        $this->setDisplayField('nombre');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('UserManager.Userstamp');

        $this->hasMany('RolesUsers', [
            'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
            'className' => 'UserManager.RolesUsers',
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinTable' => 'roles_users',
            'className' => 'UserManager.Users',
        ]);

        $this->hasMany('UsersLog', [
            'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
            'className' => 'UserManager.UsersLog',
        ]);
    }
...
}
```

```
class UserConfigTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('user_config');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('UserManager.Userstamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'LEFT',
            'className' => 'UserManager.Users',
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('UserAltas', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_alta_id',
            'joinType' => 'LEFT',
            'className' => 'UserManager.Users',
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('UserMods', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_mod_id',
            'joinType' => 'LEFT',
            'className' => 'UserManager.Users',
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('UserBajas', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_baja_id',
            'joinType' => 'LEFT',
            'className' => 'UserManager.Users',
        ]);
    }
...
}
```

```
class UserLastlogTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('user_lastlog');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
            'className' => 'Generico.Users',
        ]);
    }
...
}
```

```
class UsersLogTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('users_log');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');


        $this->belongsTo('Personas', [
            'foreignKey' => 'relacion_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
            'className' => 'UserManager.Personas',
        ]);
    }
...
}
```

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('users');
        $this->setDisplayField('username');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('Rol', [
            'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
            'className' => 'UserManager.Roles',
        ]);

        $this->hasMany('RolesUsers', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'className' => 'UserManager.RolesUsers',
        ]);
        $this->hasMany('UserConfig', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'className' => 'UserManager.UserConfig',
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Roles', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinTable' => 'user_roles',
            'className' => 'UserManager.Roles',
            'through' => 'UserManager.RolesUsers',
        ]);
    }
...
}
```

I've tried using also the require-table flag also mentioned in the docs but nathing, i reinstall the plugin, i've change the datasource, but at the moment nathing change. At this point i maight doit manually but it will be good for the futere is this is posible